# Does Nexus 4 support Desktop Convergence?

Tags: nexus-4

I want to Install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4.
But, I don't know whether the device support Desktop Convergence.
What I heard is we cannot connect keyboard and mouse to Nexus 4 via USB.
If Desktop Convergence is possible with Nexus 4, how it can be achieved?

Thanks...

Comment: Desktop convergence is not scheduled for the upcoming 13.10 release. Wait at least for the 14.04 release.

Comment: I am currently using a bluetooth keyboard and mouse with android and it workd fine. Waiting on a release of ubuntu touch that has the convergence for the nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mostly. It supports HDMI over MHL, so you can connect your Nexus 4 to your monitor or TV. You will need a bluetooth keyboard and mouse to actually control the desktop, as the Nexus 4 has no other ports.

Comment: Hi Ian, do you know the supported keyboards/mice for nexus 4?

Comment: I don't, as supported peripherals on the Nexus 4 with Android might differ when Ubuntu touch is installed.

Comment: So not Slimport?

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this link on another thread, the blogger explains his experience with Desktop convergence and has a Logitech K380 keyboard and Logitech M557 mouse.
https://sturmflut.github.io/ubuntu/convergence/2015/11/01/ubuntu-convergence-part-1/